# Webpack Dev Server not accepting mupltiple request methods for the same endpoint - POST, PATCH, DELETE

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to make Webpack Dev Server to serve different responses for different methods: POST, PATCH and DELETE.
Seems like the server accepts only POST requests. When trying to use the same endpoint for PATCH and DELETE, the server returns 404.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to handle such situation correctly. I'm using the server as a proxy for my DB, and I'm serving mocked data using it.

Comment: You got 404 because there is only the one route for the API,  which is in `POST`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a single named API which sends a different response based on different methods (`POST`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`) you need to create multiple routes to achieve that.

```
const express = require('express');
const userCtr = require('./userController');

const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.post('/ticket', userCtr.createTicket); // create a ticket
userRouter.patch('/ticket', userCtr.updateTicket); // update a ticket
userRouter.delete('/ticket', userCtr.deleteTicket); // delete a ticket

module.exports = userRouter;
```

> **Explanation**
>   On the above code, the route `/ticket` can be used in different methods which are (`POST`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`). Here The `response` will be changed according to the `method`, It helps you to make your code manageable and easy to debug.

You can also achieve this with `.all` like this

**Worst Practice**

```
userRouter.all('/ticket', userCtr.ticketOperations); // can be post/patch/delete anything
```

In this case you need to put lote more conditions into your functions like

1. `req` in `post` and have some `data` in `req.body` then create a resource.
2. `req` in `delete` have some `id` in `req.query` then remoev resources.
3. etc...

So what I suggest, If you need to generate such API which handles multiple `HTTP Methods` and treats different based on method then you need to use multiple routes along with the same name, In my instance the route name `/ticket` will used for `create/update/delete` the `ticket`.

**Best Practice**

```
userRouter.post('/ticket', userCtr.createTicket); // create a ticket
userRouter.patch('/ticket', userCtr.updateTicket); // update a ticket
userRouter.delete('/ticket', userCtr.deleteTicket); // delete a ticket
```